# Laravel Localization "fallback_locale" is not working | Laravel9 vue3 Inertia.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localization, laravel-9, inertiajs

I'm facing an issue with language switching and fallback locale in a Laravel project using Inertia.js and Vue.js. I have set up multiple language files (en.json and de.json) with translations for my application. The issue I'm encountering is that the language (en.json) works fine , but it fails to switch to the fallback locale (de) when the selected language is not supported or missing (e.g., en.json).

1- I have tried to clear the cache and view, but the issue still persists.
2- In the config/app.php file, I have set the locale to 'de' and fallback_locale to 'de' as well:

```
'locale' => 'de',
'fallback_locale' => 'de',
'supported_locales' => ['en', 'de'],
```

This is what I have done so far apart from configuration:

In my index method of product controller, I'm passing the translations to the Home.vue page and receiving it as a prop there (which is working fine) here is my controller and vue code

Controller code:

```
    public function index(){
        $locale = app()->getLocale();
        $translations = json_decode(file_get_contents(resource_path("lang/$locale.json")), true);
 
return inertia('Home',[
            'translations' => $translations,
        ]);
}
```

Home.vue code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <navbar />

        <!-- Other content of home page -->
                                <h1>{{ $t('home') }}</h1> //The output of this is Homeiesss
</div>
</template>
<script>
import navbar from "@/layouts/navbar.vue";
import footnote from "@/layouts/footer.vue";
export default {
 components: {
        navbar,
        footnote,
    },
    props: {
    translations:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        }
}
  methods: {
            $t(key) {
      return this.$page.props.translations[key] || key;
    },
</script>
```

Now Lastly here are my en.json and de.json files located in "WebRoot\resources\lang" directory and here are the content of them

en.json

```
{
    "home": "Homeiesss",
    "about_us": "About Us",
    "news": "News",
    "collection": "Collection",
    "browse": "Browse",
    "links": "Links",
    "register": "Register",
    "login": "Login",
    "language": "Language"
}
```

de.json

```
{
    "home": "Startseite",
    "about_us": "Über uns",
    "news": "Nachrichten",
    "collection": "Sammlung",
    "browse": "Durchsuchen",
    "links": "Links",
    "register": "Registrieren",
    "login": "Anmelden",
    "language": "Sprache"
}
```

Now as I mentioned, I can correctly print the content of en.json, but when the issue is that the fallback locale is not working properly, when I try to delete the en.json file, I get the following error:

```
file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\DinoToyCollection\resources\lang/en.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Now my question is: where am I making mistakes, and how can I make this dynamic? Like allowing the user to change the language from the navbar component, and it should remain persistent across all the pages.